# How much energy from lighting is converted to heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light

In a building, how much of the power used in lighting is converted to heat?  For instance, if 100 watts are used in lighting in a room, will there eventually be 100 watts of heat generated?

Comment: Yes. Except for the lights that gets absorbed by a plant that or something.

Comment: Quantum mechanics was developed partially as a result of work aimed precisely at avoiding what you are describing.  An infrared red light might be closest to your idea, but although most energy ends up as very low grade heat, that would be a very inefficient bulb.  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Walther-Nernst